# Operating System Permissions and Sec

Tags: permissions, operating-system

Im interested to know what an application's default permissions are ie. What power mainstream programs/ games have over my operating systems drivers, registry and file system and hardware. i like to know about this when designing my own apps for windows and want to progress as a security analyst and developer

Comment: That varies *widely* across operating systems and types of applications/deployment. Please be more specific.

Comment: maybe http://security.stackexchange.com/ is a better match.

Comment: Yes, it obviously varies accross platforms. I mention mainstream, and windows. Specifically im currently using windows 7 32bit, and recent version of ubuntu on my laptop, im researching whether to take win10 free upgrade to get 64bit version. But i just want to know generally how to control what an installed app has access to in windows. Ill keep researching in security.stack -thanks for the tip